# No system navigation on my magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7, system.xml, admin-panel

Like my title above is there anyone encounter that your Magento admin panel have no system navigation? I can't clear a cache, I can't install an extensions and etc..  Please check the attached file. Please help me about this problem I'm getting annoying why my Magento have no system nav .[image: no system navigation]

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Magento has roles for admin users, your user does not have the correct role to perform what you want. See [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles) for some more info, but the solution is to ask the administrator to give you (or not) the role you want.